# JOOQ - batch execution in one query with on conflict update

Tags: java, jooq

I want to do batch execution in one query , like this :

```
create.batch(create.insertInto(AUTHOR, ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME  ).values((Integer) null, null, null))
  .bind(                           1 , "Erich"   , "Gamma"    )
  .bind(                           2 , "Richard" , "Helm"     )
  .bind(                           3 , "Ralph"   , "Johnson"  )
  .bind(                           4 , "John"    , "Vlissides")
  .execute();
```

, **but the issue is that I need to add `onConflict` and `doUpdate` which I wasnt able to do.** So I need to do update on coflict of each bind.Something like that.
Please note that I can't to do this with several queries processing way.

Example source :

> [Batch execution jooq](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/)

Dependencies:

```
plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
}
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
   implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen'
}
```

Comment: Why weren't you abe to add the `onConflict()` and `doUpdate()` clauses? Just add them after `values()`

Comment: but what about binds? 
I mean for each bind I need to set different values, so this means that if I will add on conflict after values set will work for each bind? 
I was thinking this not supported

Comment: Yes, you have to provide a bind value for each effective bind parameter, as generated by jOOQ. What have you tried? Is there anything specific that's not working?

Comment: Basically what I want is bulk insert(by one query) with on conflict for each bind . I will check your last hint in my case , and will let know . Thanks a lot